# Java.lang.NullPointerException at java.awt.SystemTray.getTrayIcons(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx, java-web-start

I have a javafx project running with java web start (jnlp file)
When the application starts, it create a shortcut on the desktop and automatically starts. During startup it creates a icon in systray. When creating this systray icon, I get an error.

The code to create the systray icon is:

```
private TrayIcon trayIcon;
private PopupMenu popupMenu;

  public void createTrayIcon() {
    if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        String imageString = "image.jpg";
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(TestSystemTray.class.getResource(imageString));
        System.out.println("image is: " + image);
        popupMenu = getPopupMenu();// gets the popup with menus
        trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Test application", popupMenu);
        try {
            if (tray != null) {
                System.out.println("Tray is no null: " + tray);
                if (trayIcon != null) {
                    System.out.println("trayIcon is no null:" + trayIcon);
                    trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
                    setEventHandler();
                    tray.add(trayIcon);
                    showProgramIsMinimizedMsg();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("trayIcon is null");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("tray is null");
            }

        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't add tray to systemtray" + e.getMessage() + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I think this happens because when calling "tray.add(trayIcon);"  tray calles getTrayIcons(); with in my case gives an nullpointer and java.awt.SystemTray.getTrayIcons(**Unknown Source)**. To comfirm this I added "TrayIcon[] icons = tray.getTrayIcons();" and "System.out.println("getTrayIcons() is: " + icons);"  before calling  "tray.add(trayIcon)" and it was confirmed.

This strange thing, is that if i close the applicaition and re open it trough the desktop shortcut, the error no longer occurs.

FYI: The JNLP file contains all-permissions and al the JAR files are signed and approved. Java 1.8.0_05

Anyone?

Comment: *"..strange thing, is that if i close the applicaition and re open it trough the desktop shortcut, the error no longer occurs."*  Have you checked the [bug database](http://bugs.java.com/)?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find anything relevant

Comment: Try raising a bug report and see what Oracle has to say about it.